# Is it necessary to root devices to be able to access scoped storage?

Tags: permissions, adb, aws-device-farm, scoped-storage, rooted-device

We are currently using AWS Device Farm for testing android applications. Using AWS device farm, first the apk is built. Then, the required artifacts are placed  in the testing device's scoped storage. Then, the application is ran(which uses these artifacts).
Lately, I have been facing the following issue when trying to push the artifacts:
(Consider my app's package is "com.myapp")

[  5%] /sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp/files/MyFolder/scripts.zip

[ 11%] /sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp/files/MyFolder/scripts.zip

[ 16%] /sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp/files/MyFolder/scripts.zip

[ 22%] /sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp/files/MyFolder/scripts.zip

[ 27%] /sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp/files/MyFolder/scripts.zip

[ 33%] /sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp/files/MyFolder/scripts.zip

[ 38%] /sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp/files/MyFolder/scripts.zip

[ 44%] /sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp/files/MyFolder/scripts.zip

[ 49%] /sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp/files/MyFolder/scripts.zip

[ 55%] /sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp/files/MyFolder/scripts.zip

[ 60%] /sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp/files/MyFolder/scripts.zip

[ 66%] /sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp/files/MyFolder/scripts.zip

[ 71%] /sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp/files/MyFolder/scripts.zip

[ 77%] /sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp/files/MyFolder/scripts.zip

[ 82%] /sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp/files/MyFolder/scripts.zip

[ 88%] /sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp/files/MyFolder/scripts.zip

[ 93%] /sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp/files/MyFolder/scripts.zip

[ 99%] /sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp/files/MyFolder/scripts.zip

[100%] /sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp/files/MyFolder/scripts.zip

**adb: error: failed to copy 'scripts.zip' to '/sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp/files/MyFolder/scripts.zip': remote secure_mkdirs failed: Permission denied**
on GOOGLE PIXEL 5 (UNLOCKED)  OS 11

Whereas the same logic worked on a few set of devices:

SAMSUNG GALAXY S20 (UNLOCKED) 10

SAMSUNG GALAXY S9 (UNLOCKED) 9

The following command is run to push the scripts.zip file:
adb push scripts.zip /sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp/files/MyFolder/scripts.zip

I read a lot of articles about this error but all of them were using rooted device. Thus on running certain commands, they were able to fix it. In my case, aws cloud contains real device on which the testcases are run and thus rooting the device is not possible.

My requirement is to push the artifact into the scoped storage of my own application using cmd commands.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: does the answer below helps to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The scoped storage location of your own app on Pixel devices is

```
/data/data/com.myapp/files
```

to copy a file into this folder you can copy it into a temporary location:

```
adb push scripts.zip /data/local/tmp/scripts.zip
```

then copy the uploaded file into the app's private location:

```
adb shell run-as com.myapp cp /data/local/tmp/scripts.zip .
```